# Need help to parameterize JSON values in the web custom request

Tags: loadrunner

I need help to parameterize the JSON values in the web custom request code. I am newbie to LR and need to know how to parameterize the username and password values in my custom request.

```
     web_custom_request("authenticate_2", 
    "URL=some.com/authenticate", 
    "Method=POST", 
    "Resource=0", 
    "RecContentType=application/vnd.api+json", 
    "Referer=some.com/login", 
    "Snapshot=t272.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    "EncType=application/json; charset=UTF-8", 
    "Body{\"username\":\"1A\",\"password\":\"bac\",\"grant_type\":\"password\"}", 
    EXTRARES, 
    "Url=auction", "Referer=some.com/login", ENDITEM,
    LAST
```

Comment: Why did you chose Web HTTP/HTML protocol over TruWeb protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps:
Basically you select the value in Vugen and right-click to create a parameter.

[image: Adding a parameter]